# Make my array zero keeping some indices as it is

Tags: ios, arrays, filter, swift5, xcode10

I have an array 'board_matrix' with some values in it. And I also have another array 'win' with some indices values. Now I want to make 'board_matrix' go all zero except those **indices** in 'win' array.

say,

```
board_matrix = [1,0,2,2,1,0,1,0,1]
win = [0,4,8]

then output should be 
new_array = [1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1]
```

Comment: If you have win indices, why not to create a new array to alter the values based on comparing the values on specified indices...

Comment: I too want to create a new array , but I can't compare the value of indices

Comment: Can you change `win` to a `Set<Int>`? Then you can iterate over the array and use `win.contains(index)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the board_matrix array and overwrite the values if the index is not found in the win array. Something like this:

```
for (i=0; i<board_matrix.size; i++) {
    if (!win.contains(i)) board_matrix[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not Swift, and it's O(board_matrix.count * win.count).

Answer (score 0):

```swift
board_matrix.enumerated().map { [winIndices = Set(win)] in
  winIndices.contains($0.offset) ? $0.element : 0
}
```